# What are the Dimensions for designing layout for Pixel 2 XL?

Tags: android

I have a Layout-sw400dp(among others) folder in my layouts folder for supporting different screens. The layout I have designed works fine for Pixel and other devices but it doesn't work for Pixel 2 XL, from what I've learned Pixel and Pixel 2 XL have the same width but different height.

I want to design a layout for Pixel 2 XL devices, I tried different things but it's not helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe6kF.png)
[Pixel 2 XL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI6Gk.png)

Comment: Have u read this [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Comment: Looks like your views are not constraint properly. Dimensions Should not affect this if you make layout properly ..

Comment: @ADM Yeah you're right man, it's actually about the constraints. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, I observe the pixel 2 xl support drawable and dimension from the following folder

```
drawable-sw380dp-xhdpi
values-sw380dp-xhdpi
```

Comment: But layout xml files doesn't work when you put it in these folders.